# Storing Sortables in localStorage

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, local-storage

http://jsfiddle.net/2H2rx/

Having Trouble retaining changes to the last item in a sortable list.

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).on("sortupdate",function( event, ui ) {
      var sorted = $( this ).sortable( "serialize");
      console.log(sorted);
      localStorage.setItem('sorted', sorted) ;

});

if(localStorage.getItem("sorted") !== null){
  var arrValuesForOrder = localStorage.getItem('sorted').substring(6).split("&div[]="); 

  var $ul = $("#sortable");
  $items = $("#sortable").children();

// loop backwards so you can just prepend elements in the list
// instead of trying to place them at a specific position
  for (var i = arrValuesForOrder[arrValuesForOrder.length - 1]; i >= 0; i--) {
    // index is zero-based to you have to remove one from the values in your array
    $ul.prepend( $items.get((arrValuesForOrder[i] - 1)));
  }
}

$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

I'm trying to code a way to store sortables in local storage.  I'm having a little trouble that seems to hinge on the last item, and it happens intermittently, after a few times.  Something is breaking it?  It will not load changes to the last item after a few times, or will arbitrarily reorder them.  I can't tell.   To replicate, you must load link, reorder a few times, run a few times, reorder some more.  It eventually wont retain the changes to the last item, at least in Chrome 27.0.1453.110 m.  Haven't checked other browsers.

I see a bunch of other questions asking similar things to this, but I've actually got a semi-working solution now, just having trouble debugging.

Edit:  It appears that the error happens when #1, 2, or 3 is in the final position.  Maybe not a rule, but that's an easier way for me to replicate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is using one of the values for the starting index rather than the actual length of the array, the correct for loop header should be as follows.

```
for (var i = arrValuesForOrder.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
```